# dart, reflection and source maps?

Tags: dart, bundling-and-minification, source-maps

I have a proxy object which uses `noSuchMethod` to relay invocations to other objects, but the proxy object exists in a minified/obfuscated environment, and the objects it relays the invocations to are in a non-minified/obfuscated state, so when the name of the method being called reaches the non-minified environment the names don't match up, I have the myFile.dart.js.map file, is there a simple algorithm to parse this and get the original invocation name back from the minified name using the source maps? or even better is there a library that already does this in dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MirrorSystem.getName](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-mirrors.MirrorSystem@id_getName) to get the real name of a symbol. In the case of `noSuchMethod` :

```dart
noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
  String member = MirrorSystem.getName(invocation.memberName);
}
```

Comment: will this work in an obfuscated environment? e.g. `myProxy.jumpAround()` when minified to javascript becomes `aG.d()` or something similar, so then wouldn't member in your example be equal to "d"? or does MirrorSystem keep an internal map of all the minified names to original names? which if it does, I'm a very happy person and this question wasn't necessary.

Comment: `MirrorSystem.getName` has been done exactly for this purpose. It keeps the original names. Be careful of `@MirrorsUsed` that can reduce the retained names. In your example `member` will be `jumpAround`.

Comment: is there a method for getting a non-minified string to its minified form? I was looking at `MirrorSystem.getSymbol(str)` but I need the minified string rather than the symbol represented by that string.

Comment: No but I cannot imagine a case where you would have to do such a thing.